# OpenERP XML-RPC working fine on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, odoo

I have an OpenERP system setup on a VPS, and I had created a PHP class to connect to it.

The class works fine when I execute it through the localhost. But when I upload the files on a live server, it gives an error:

> "Unable to login Connect error: Connection timed out (110)"

Here is the class I have created.

```
include_once("xmlrpc.inc");
class OpenERPXmlrpc {
    private $user, $password, $database, $services, $client, $res, $msg, $id;
    function __construct($usr, $pass, $db, $server) {
      $this->user = $usr;
      $this->password = $pass;
      $this->database = $db;
      $this->services = $server;
      $this->client = new xmlrpc_client($this->services.'common');
      $this->msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
      $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->database, "string"));
      $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->user, "string"));   
      $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));
      $this->res =  &$this->client->send($this->msg);
      if(!$this->res->faultCode()){
         $this->id = $this->res->value()->scalarval();
      }
      else {
         echo "Unable to login ".$this->res->faultString();
         exit;
      }
   }
// Some Methods...
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (live, server, localhost) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: As for the problem, a connection timeout should be pretty obvious to debug.  Have you already made sure that there are no firewall rules in the way?

Comment: Thanks charles for your reply, I already checked it by increasing the time out to around 3000 sec's but it still has the same problem. There are no firewall restrictions on the Openerp server, i confirmed it from their support guys.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Have same problem in live server!?

Comment: it was a while back and dont remember correctly, but you should confirm that both the systems are actually using https (ssl). i was using openerp7 at that time and besides tons of other bugs the api was really bad. The documentation was also confusing with different versions being used in the wild with no backward compatibility. But now openerp has been converted to odoo and the current version is odoo 9. Its much better then the previous one. You should try migrating to the latest one, everything is much simpler now.